# Capture user input by opening a text editor with content

Tags: bash, input, editor, prompt

From a bash script, I'd like to

1. Open the default text editor for current user
2. Paste a string `$original_content` in it
3. Once the user modifies the content then closes the text editor,
4. Capture the modified string into a variable `$modified_content`
5. Then save `$modified_content` to an `$output_file`

Google searches for capturing user input shows `read` which is not what I'm looking for.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Is `$original_content`  to be "pasted" into a new empty document? ... (in other words are you just wanting to use the editor as a dialog box? ... you can use `zenity` for a dialog ... Come to think of it, you can use `zenity` as a basic editor even if pre-existing text is involved.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the text editor as a full-featured dialog box. How does zenity fare in CLI mode? Do you think it's better than Manny's solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method should hopefully work for most editors:

```
#!/bin/bash

original_content="Your original content"

echo $original_content > /tmp/user_input.tmp

# For example:
# DEFAULT_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vi
$DEFAULT_EDITOR /tmp/user_input.tmp

modified_content=`cat /tmp/user_input.tmp`

echo $modified_content > /tmp/output_file
```

This script may be a little drawn out but it performs all the actions you wanted except for the pasting part, since you'd probably have to accommodate for all varieties of editors to properly "paste" a string. This script utilizes the benefit that calling most editors with a filename as a parameter opens that file for editing thereby "pasting" your `$original_content` in the editor.

Comment: This sounds promising. Is this what SVN or Git does when it asks for a commit message? Also, is there a way to use the default editor for that user(stored in EDITOR variable), rather than me specifying an editor? Thanks!