# How to pipe Vim output buffer into a command line argument for a different command?

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to write a bash command that will prompt user for a multiline input via text editor (vim or nano or emacs) and inject it as part of the argument.

For instance, if I run a git command
`git commit --amend -m "<MY DESIRED MESSAGE>"` it will revise the commit message with that desired message.

However, if I do just

`git commit --amend` it will open up a command line editor and prompt for commit message, and once I save it will be injected into command messages.

Also, in addition, is there a way to store input received from read and store it in the variable?

Thank you in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375434/capture-user-input-by-opening-a-text-editor-with-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is have the editor write to a file and then use the file content as argument.

Eg:

```
nano /tmp/test.txt; git commit -m "$(cat /tmp/test.txt)"; rm /tmp/test.txt
```

Comment: thanks. What about using `read` command? Is there a way to store whatever's obtained from read?

I want to have prompt-response-prompt-response till there's no response from the input